ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2). Using mariadb on Debian trixie
I'm aware this is a common issue, but none of the other posts helped me solve our issue (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ).
I installed mariadb using an ansible as part of an openstack installation, and it crashed with the following error:

Ansible task:
  name: DB - setting /root/.my.cnf
    become: true
    copy:
      dest: /root/.my.cnf
      content: |
        [client]
        user=root
        password="{{ DB_root_password }}"
        socket  = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    tags: db_config

  - name: DB - Configure MariaDB
    become: true
    template:
      src: openstack.cnf
      dest: /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/openstack.cnf
    tags: db_config

  - name: DB - configure keystone access 1/3
    become: true
    template:
      src: keystone.sql.j2
      dest: /root/keystone.sql
    tags: db_config

  - name: DB - grant access to Keystone 2/3
    become: true
    shell: mysql -u root < /root/keystone.sql
    tags: db_config


Error:



"stderr": "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local server through
socket '/var/run mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)"


More info:

~# service mariadb status
Process: 1039769 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 1039771 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 1039852 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mariadbd $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=killed, signal=ILL)
Main PID: 1039852 (code=killed, signal=ILL)
Mem peak: 5.4M
CPU: 606ms
Nov 05 14:41:26 controller01 systemd[1]: Failed to start mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.11.3 database server.


I also get the same error (ERROR 2002 (HY000)) when I run the commands mysql or mariadb.
I tried manually installing mariadb but the output is the same.
I tried mariadb_safe but the socket is not created


Trixie is in testing. Have you verified it's not a bug?

Hi @vidarlo! Yes, and the only known bug relating mariadb and debian trixie is this

The only useful bit of information in your post is "Failed to start mariadb.service". Everything else is a symptom of that. Check your log files and learn how to use systemctl to manage services.

Hi @symcbean! I have no /var/log/mysql/ nor /var/log/mariadb/ directories, and journalctl returns the same log as systemctl or service do (which I already posted above). Do you have any other advice? Thanks!

Check the log paths in the config file / ensure the DBMS will write log where you can read them.
